# Are Uchihas affected by Infinite Tsukuyomi?

Tags: naruto

Just wondering if the Uchiha family members are unaffected by Infinite Tsukuyomi, or if it was Sasuke's Susanno that protected him against it?

Answer (score 3):

This [link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi) would give you the answer.

> Despite the seemingly inescapable nature of this technique, the Infinite Tsukuyomi can be countered through specific means:
>
> 1. The user's Rinne Sharingan only reflects off of the moon for a limited period of time after the technique has been activated, allowing those who avoid its light to avoid being trapped within the genjutsu. Using his Rinnegan, Sasuke Uchiha was able to shield himself and his team by covering them with his Susanoo.
> 2. Believing that this genjutsu was cast using a Rinnegan, Sasuke hypothesised that it can be cancelled by another Rinnegan. Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki confirmed this, but revealed that the chakra of the nine tailed beasts is also required, and that a person with said chakra and a Rinnegan user must form the rat hand seal together, though Sasuke claimed he would be able to cancel the technique alone using the tailed beasts under his control. Upon the technique's cancellation, the roots used to bind the victims wither, as do all remaining White Zetsu.

"The user's Rinne Sharingan only reflects off of the moon for a limited period of time after the technique has been activated, allowing those who avoid its light to avoid being trapped within the genjutsu. Using his Rinnegan, Sasuke Uchiha was able to shield himself and his team by covering them with his Susanoo."

Answer (score -1):

It was indeed the defence of the Susanoo. It is said that not even light can penetrate it's defence. This is by far the only way of defending against the Infinite Tskuyoumi while its cast.

The Susanoo is just high density chakra,
but in Boruto

> Jigen penetrated through it like butter!